# iOS Lock Screen Icon Questions

Tags: icon, ios

I am looking for some information on lock screen icons in iOS. The icon type I am referring to is the small one in the lower left corner.

[image]

Also mentioned in this article: http://blog.estimote.com/post/97824495825/ios-8-pushes-location-context-to-a-new-level-lock

My two main questions are:

1. Does anyone know what size this icon should be delivered at?
2. Is this delivered as an independent icon or does iOS create this icon based on your home screen icon.

I have been looking online for information all morning and can't find any guidelines.

Comment: That icon isn't present on my iPhone... and never has been as far as I know.

Comment: Let me get out my microscope for that icon in the image...

Answer (score 0):

I can't find any reference to which exact size icon is used, but it looks like one of the smaller app icons. You can find info on the different app icons you can supply with an app on the apple developer library [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1686/_index.html) and [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/ExpectedAppBehaviors/ExpectedAppBehaviors.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH3-SW1).

iOS should use the closest appropriate sized icon you supply, and if no smaller icon is available it will shrink the home screen icon as you said.

From the iOS Human Interface Guidelines:

> iOS chooses an icon based on whether its size is appropriate for the intended usage

and

> If you don’t provide these icons, iOS might shrink your app icon

You can read more about app icons on the iOS Human Interface Guidelines [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/AppIcons.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH19-SW1) and [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/IconMatrix.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH27-SW2).

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's the same size icon that is used in settings and all other notification popups.

[image]

The dimensions for these icon are:

- @3x = 87px x 87px
- @2x = 58px x 58px
- @1x = 29px x 29px

And as @Cai has stated above you can see these dimensions [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1686/_index.html), under the file names (Icon-Small.png, Icon-Small@2x.png, Icon-Small@3x.png).

You can also download a free template here: http://appicontemplate.com/ios8/

Comment: Hi Joshua, welcome to GDSE and thanks for your answer. If you have any questions, please see the [help] or ping one of us in the [chat] once your reputation is sufficient (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!